# Pinging local host doesn't function

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, ping

elasticsearch==7.10.0

I wish to ping local host '5601' to ensure kibana is running or not but apparently unable to ping.

Note: I am aware that elastic search has in-built function to ping but I still wish to ping using cmd line for a specific reason in my project.

```
C:\User>ping 5601

Pinging f00:b00:f00:b00 with 32 bytes of data:
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
PING: transmit failed. General failure.

Ping statistics for f00:b00:f00:b00:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss)

C:\User>ping http://localhost:5601
Ping request could not find host http://localhost:5601. Please check the name and try again.
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: What is 5601? That's not a proper address.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Received this message while giving hostname in ping command. Ping request could not find host http://localhost:5601. Please check the name and try again.

Comment: If 5601 is a port number, you can't ping a specific port because pings use ICMP, which doesn't have any notion of port numbers, because it doesn't use TCP or UDP. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: You could try `netstat -ab` to see what programs are listening for connections on what ports if you want to verify that a program is listening. Make sure to run `cmd` as an admin to use the `b` option though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `netstat` to check if the port exposed by the Kibana UI, 5061 is in LISTEN mode

```
$ netstat -tlpn | grep 5601
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp6       0      0 :::5601                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

Or if you want to establish a connection to destination port 5601 you can use `nc`

```
$ nc -vz localhost 5601
Connection to localhost 5601 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```